# google app script help to optimize my script

Tags: google-apps-script

Can somebody help to optimize my script.

I use it on my payroll system. Below is my sample script that I used for two person payroll, but my actual script is for 80 person of same formula, only differ is the range list.

So in result I'm having a timeout, because of large number of data. I need to create multiple function in order for me to accomplish the entire script..

Is there a way or formula that I can use to speed up my script?

P.S. I'm just a beginner, thanks.[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITpji.png) 
. based on my image the in and out 10:00 -15:00    19:00-22:00 so what i want to happen is to be able to replace them with 8:00-12:00  13:00-17:00 through script but the thing is that  i do have tons of table need to be replaced that why i use allot of getrange and getactiverange is there a way for me or a loop to fix my problem

```
function CLEAR2() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var PAYSLIP = ss.getSheetByName('PAYSLIP');

PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['c717','C719','C721','C723','C725']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().setValue('8:00');
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['D717','D719','D721','D723','D725','D727']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().setValue('12:00');
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['E717','E719','E721','E723','E725','E727']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().setValue('13:00');
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['F717','F719','F721','F723','F725']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().setValue('17:00');
PAYSLIP.getRange('C727').activate();
PAYSLIP.getCurrentCell().setValue('7:00');
PAYSLIP.getRange('f727').activate();
PAYSLIP.getCurrentCell().setValue('16:00';
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['A715:A716','C715:F716','C718:F718','C720:F720','C722:F722','C724:F724','C726:F726','C728:F728','J715:J728']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['K715:O728','S715:T728','N733:P746','S733:T746']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['c754','C756','C758','C760','C762']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().setValue('8:00');
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['D754','D756','D758','D760','D762','D764']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().setValue('12:00');
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['E754','E756','E758','E760','E762','E764']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().setValue('13:00');
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['F754','F756','F758','F760','F762']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().setValue('17:00');
PAYSLIP.getRange('C764').activate();
PAYSLIP.getCurrentCell().setValue('7:00');
PAYSLIP.getRange('f764').activate();
PAYSLIP.getCurrentCell().setValue('16:00');
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['A752:A753','C752:F753','C755:F755','C757:F757','C759:F759','C761:F761','C763:F763','C765:F765','J752:J765']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
PAYSLIP.getRangeList(['K752:O765','S752:T765','N770:P783','S770:T783']).activate();
PAYSLIP.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
```

Comment: What you want to optimize in the script, it is still not clear what is your expected output. Your inputs are not clear!

Comment: I don't know about other volunteer here at SO but when I see macro codes which include excessive use of activate and activeRange my mind just shuts off and I don't even try to read it.  From point of view you would be better to explain what you want in words and images rather then providing macro code.  Personally, I will not even read it or try to understand it.

Comment: @vector thank you sir  i added  a picture and  based on my image the in and out 10:00 -15:00 19:00-22:00 so what i want to happen is to be able to replace them with 8:00-12:00 13:00-17:00 through script but the thing is that i do have tons of table need to be replaced that why i use allot of getrange and getactiverange is there a way for me or a loop to fix my problem

Comment: @Cooper i added a link of the image basically i want to replace the time from  10:00 -15:00 19:00-22:00  to 8:00-12:00 13:00-17:00  but i have tons of tables with same thing must be done  i dont know the right formula to use

Comment: Like I said  I haven't even read your code and I'm not going to.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, you can achieve that by using just a formula, if that's the only requirement you've there is no need to put that code.

> i want to replace the time from 10:00 -15:00 19:00-22:00 to 8:00-12:00 13:00-17:00 but i have tons of tables with same thing must be done i dont know the right formula to use

Try using this formula:

```
=TIME(HOUR(N7)-2,MINUTE(N7),SECOND(N7))
```

Replace N7 with cell reference of time from which you want to subtract/add an hour, here I am subtracting  **-2** from hour, you can change the logic based on your use case scenario.

**Reference:**

[TIME](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093056?hl=en)